# How can I be sure that the request is being sent by Stripe and not by a third party?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, payment

I am working on my application with the Django backend and the Angular frontend and I am gonna use Stripe. At this point everything seems to be working properly. It looks something like shown below. I would like to be sure that I do everything properly and in a secure way. I found [Best practices for using webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices) and there is recommendation about adding `@require_POST` and `@csrf_exempt` decorators. I guess that I do not need them because Django automatically handle requests other than POST method in my Generic API View and there is also no problem with CSRF so it seems to me that I do not have to disable CSRF protection? I have also doubts how can I be sure that the request is being sent by Stripe and not by a third party? Let's say we have scenario that someone creates an account in the form on the page with amount equals to 10000$ and it goes through the first card verification. He does not have sufficient funds in his account and the transaction is declined however he sends a fake request to my `my_stripe_url/` endpoint with status `invoice.payment_succeeded`. The question is whether Stripe supports it by default and prevents such cases or whether any additional actions, such as usage for example [webhook signatures](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures), must be done on my part to prevent such situations?

Django:

urls:

```
url(r'^my_stripe_url/', views.StripeView.as_view()),
```

views:

@schema(None)
class StripeView(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = UserNameSerializer

```
def post(self, request):

    payload = request.body
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
            json.loads(payload), stripe.api_key
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if event.type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded':

        payment_invoice = event.data.object

        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(payment_invoice['subscription'])

        account = Account.objects.filter(subscription=payment_invoice['subscription'])

        account.update(
            payment_successful=True)

        account.update(
            current_period_start=datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription['current_period_start']))

        account.update(
            current_period_end=datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription['current_period_end']))

        return HttpResponse(status=200)


    elif event.type == 'invoice.payment_failed':

        payment_invoice = event.data.object

        account = Account.objects.filter(subscription=payment_invoice['subscription'])

        account.update(
            payment_successful=False)

        return HttpResponse(status=200)

    else:
        
        # Unexpected event type
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify webhook event requests are coming from Stripe you should [verify webhook signatures](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures) (that's the same link you have in your question, just linked here again for easy reference).  This is what the signatures are designed to do.  From the Stripe docs:

> Stripe can optionally sign the webhook events it sends to your endpoints by including a signature in each event’s `Stripe-Signature` header. This allows you to verify that the events were sent by Stripe, not by a third party.

The CSRF changes are only required if you're having trouble receiving webhook event requests due to those security measures, and are unrelated to verifying the authenticity of the webhook requests.